# CLI arguments are not processed in conftest.py in my pytest

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, pytest, fixtures

My project implementation is to capture details from CLI to determine the environment, to generate the token in that environment and to return the token and the application URL.

Here is the code in conftest.py file

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
parser.addoption('--env',
                 dest='testenv',
                 choices=["qa","aws","prod"],
                 default='qa',
                 help='Specify environment: "qa", "aws", "prod".')

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
#def conftest_setup(request):
  #  env = request.config.getoption("--env")

def conftest_setup(request):
    env = request.config.getoption("--env")
    print(env)
    if (env =='aws'):
        url='AWSURL'
    elif ( env =='prod'):
        url='prodURL'
    else:
        url='QAURL'

    token = requests.post(auth=HTTPBasicAuth(clientID, secret),headers=tokenheaders, data=payload)
    auth = token.json()['access_token']
    return auth,url
```

test_service.py  has

```
auth1=''
url1=''

def initialCall(conftest_setup):
    auth1=conftest_setup[1]  # Pretty sure this is wrong, but couldnt get a way to retrieve this
    url1=conftest_setup[2]


# Now I want to use the auth1 and url1 obtained from above method to the below method
def response():
    print("auth is " ,auth1)
    print("URL is " ,url1)
    headers = {'content-type': 'application/json',
              'Authorization' : auth1}
    response= 
        (requests.post(url1,data=json.dumps(data1),headers=headers)).json()
```

Currently, I get this exception

```
request = <FixtureRequest for <Function 

>   ???

test\test_service_1.py:41:
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
..\..\software\python\lib\site-packages\pytest_bdd\scenario.py:195: in _execute_scenario
    _execute_step_function(request, scenario, step, step_func)
..\..\software\python\lib\site-packages\pytest_bdd\scenario.py:136: in _execute_step_function
    step_func(**kwargs)
..\..\software\python\lib\site-packages\pytest_bdd\steps.py:164: in step_func
    result = request.getfixturevalue(func.__name__)
..\..\software\python\lib\site-packages\_pytest\fixtures.py:478: in getfixturevalue
    return self._get_active_fixturedef(argname).cached_result[0]
..\..\software\python\lib\site-packages\_pytest\fixtures.py:501: in _get_active_fixturedef
    self._compute_fixture_value(fixturedef)
..\..\software\python\lib\site-packages\_pytest\fixtures.py:586: in _compute_fixture_value
    fixturedef.execute(request=subrequest)
..\..\software\python\lib\site-packages\_pytest\fixtures.py:895: in execute
    return hook.pytest_fixture_setup(fixturedef=self, request=request)
..\..\software\python\lib\site-packages\pluggy\hooks.py:289: in __call__
    return self._hookexec(self, self.get_hookimpls(), kwargs)
..\..\software\python\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py:68: in _hookexec
    return self._inner_hookexec(hook, methods, kwargs)
..\..\software\python\lib\site-packages\pluggy\manager.py:62: in <lambda>
    firstresult=hook.spec.opts.get("firstresult") if hook.spec else False,
..\..\software\python\lib\site-packages\_pytest\fixtures.py:937: in pytest_fixture_setup
    result = call_fixture_func(fixturefunc, request, kwargs)
..\..\software\python\lib\site-packages\_pytest\fixtures.py:794: in call_fixture_func
    res = fixturefunc(**kwargs)



 ***test\test_service_1.py:40: in testws_response
        response=(requests.post(url1,data=json.dumps(data1),headers=headers)).json()***


..\..\software\python\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py:116: in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
..\..\software\python\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py:60: in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
..\..\software\python\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py:519: in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
..\..\software\python\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py:462: in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
..\..\software\python\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py:313: in prepare
    self.prepare_url(url, params)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <PreparedRequest [POST]>, url = '', params = OrderedDict()

    def prepare_url(self, url, params):
        """Prepares the given HTTP URL."""
        #: Accept objects that have string representations.
        #: We're unable to blindly call unicode/str functions
        #: as this will include the bytestring indicator (b'')
        #: on python 3.x.
        #: https://github.com/requests/requests/pull/2238
        if isinstance(url, bytes):
            url = url.decode('utf8')
        else:
            url = unicode(url) if is_py2 else str(url)

        # Remove leading whitespaces from url
        url = url.lstrip()

        # Don't do any URL preparation for non-HTTP schemes like `mailto`,
        # `data` etc to work around exceptions from `url_parse`, which
        # handles RFC 3986 only.
        if ':' in url and not url.lower().startswith('http'):
            self.url = url
            return

        # Support for unicode domain names and paths.
        try:
            scheme, auth, host, port, path, query, fragment = parse_url(url)
        except LocationParseError as e:
            raise InvalidURL(*e.args)

        if not scheme:
            error = ("Invalid URL {0!r}: No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://{0}?")
            error = error.format(to_native_string(url, 'utf8'))

>           raise MissingSchema(error)
E           requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL '': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://?

..\..\software\python\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py:387: MissingSchema
```

**No console output observed for print(env) in conftest.py file while 
    auth is  None
    URL IS    None
are observed for print statements in test_service**

CLI execution throws error when I pass pytest -s --env='qa' but is acceptable for pytest -s --env=qa. So the CLI arguments are captured.

Please help me to capture the auth and url from conftest.py across the test file.

Also, is there a way I can use this auth,url returned from conftest.py to use across multiple test files?

Comment: The exception simply says that your URL doesn't have a valid scheme, e.g. it's `www.example.com` instead of `https://www.example.com`

Comment: Thanks @hoefling for the reply. I tried the URL as mentioned but still see the issue. I am wondering why the print statements in conftest.py are not executed. The URL1 and auth values are shown None in test_service.py

Comment: Ah, I see. `initialCall` is not a fixture and is not called anywhere. Decorate it with `@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)` and it will be executed by `pytest` before each test; or decorate with `@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope='session')` and `pytest` will execute it once before all tests.

Comment: Another thing is that Python counts from zero, so access auth via `conftest_setup[0]` and url via `conftest_setup[1]`.

Comment: In general, while your approach with global vars is not wrong, I would rather declare separate fixtures `auth` returning `conftest_setup[0]` and `url` returning `conftest_setup[1]` and use them in tests where necessary. I'd even move the code from `conftest_setup` into those two fixtures to clearly separate the two.

Comment: Thank you @hoefling. This is working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to @hoefling for providing valuable insights.

I've added/updated the fixture in the following places and declared auth1 and url1 as global inside initialcall method. It now works as expected.

test_service.py has

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope='session')
def initialCall(conftest_setup):
    global auth1,AN_API1
    auth1 = conftest_setup[0]
    AN_API1=conftest_setup[1]
```

conftest.py has

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True,scope='session')
def conftest_setup(request):
```